# Spring oauth2 add additional fieldp

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

After login /uaa/oauth/token spring send that fields:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbG",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "asfasfda"
  "expires_in": 86399,
  "scope": "events",
  "jti": "a4e4584c-ed38-4a26-b778-1748b27046ae",
  "key" : "my own field"
}
```

But how can i add my own custom fields, for example key?

Comment: You can send custom key/value pair on that request and use filter to intercept and read extra key value params?

Comment: I do not think that is clear solution

Comment: I don't think it's that bad as it sounds. I basically configure a filter in my security configuration. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(Constants.RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
            .addFilter(new AuthTokenRequestFilter())
           .....
        }
}
```